# What do you call crazy eyes?

Tags: word-request

What do you call crazy eyes? Let's say that the eyes are looking at different direction, and we're talking about the eyes of the same person. What do you call eyes like that? Cross-eyes?

> This man has cross-eyes? He looks a bit stupid or crazy.

Is that the right word, expression?

Comment: To call someone stupid or crazy because they have crossed eyes is highly offensive.  I suggest you edit your example

Answer (score 1):

To be very scientific, the term you are looking for is probably "strabismus" (pronounced /strəˈbɪzməs/) . Wikipedia defines strabismus as:

> A condition in which the eyes do not properly align with each other when looking at an object.
>
> ([Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strabismus), n. d.)

There are several kinds of strabismus, see the picture below.

[image]

But if you are talking to a lay person, I think "crossed eyes" is fine:

> This man has crossed eyes? He looks a bit stupid or crazy.

Answer (score -1):

The term "cross-eyed" can be used to refer to the specific situation where a person's eyes are pointed toward each other, as though they were attempting to focus on an object that's extremely close to their face. It can be used as an adjective or an adverb.

> That poor man is cross-eyed. It makes him look a bit stupid or crazy.

> Why is that woman looking at me cross-eyed? Is there something on my face?

> Trying to look at abstract paintings always makes me go all cross-eyed.

If there's something else unusual about a person's eyes other than that specific situation, then the word wouldn't apply. For example, if a person's eyes are pointing *away* from each other, then the term would be "wall-eyed". (Although this term is much less common than "cross-eyed" -- perhaps because this condition is less common.)